# Submit an iOS application with login

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to ask a question about submit process of an iOS application. The application which I would to submit has a private area accessible by credentials. Have I to send the credentials to Apple for testing?

Thanks,
S.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the app, there is a field near the bottom of screen saying **Review Notes** . You can add the test credentials there, which will be noticed by the reviewers at Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should give Apple the credentials. There is box in iTunes Connect where you can give Apple the extra information needed to test the app.